# CK Editor and doksoft_uploader image upload, base configuration

Tags: php, ckeditor

The code below is from a "config" file that controls a doksoft_uploader plugin inside WYSIWYG CK Editor.

See code:

```
    <?php

// Absolute URL to upload folder via HTTP.
// Will affect to client (JS) part of plugins.
// By default script is configured to automatically detect it.
// If you want to change it, do it like this:
// $config['BaseUrl'] = 'http://yoursite.com/ckeditor_or_tinymce/plugins/doksoft_uploader/';

$config['BaseUrl'] = 'http://havanarumbaonline.com/web/HAVRUM/assets';

// Absolute or relative path to directory on the server where uploaded files will be stored.
// Used by this PHP script only.
// By default it automatically detects the directory.
// You can change it, see this example:
// $config['BaseDir'] = "/var/www/ckeditor/doksoft_uploader/userfiles/";
// Orginal --> $config['BaseDir'] = dirname(__FILE__).'/userfiles/';

// Support Suggestion --> $config['BaseDir'] = dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$userid.'/assets/';
//$config['BaseDir'] = dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$userid.'userfiles/';

$config['BaseDir'] = '/home/content/28/6823828/html/havanarumba/web/HAVRUM/assets';
```

---

### Disregard all the comments above - BUT I did want to include them as they are from the developer and it may provide some insight. When I use the two "$config['BaseUrl']" above - I am getting an errors.

Upon clicking the "add image" icon inside CK Editor, a dialogue box appears,user selects an image,  then the code is suppose to upload the image to the proper directory and then show the image in the CK Editor edit area. But the image appears as missing in the editor. When I view the source code, I get:

The code is suppose to

NOTE: I have used this code many times successfully but this one is not working. A hint may be it is a GoDaddy account. GoDaddy says these are the configurations:

IP Address
97.74.46.128

DNS (Primary Domain)
Preview Manage

Operating System
LINUX

PHP Version
5

Hostname
mojitotapas.com

Absolute Hosting Path 
/home/content/28/6823828/html

Hosting Configuration 
2.2

IMPORTANT: This hosting account in registered as mojitotapas.com, but the domain havanarumbaonline.com IS ALSO attached to the account in a subdirectory. GoDaddy allows you to have multiple domains hosted but each go into their own directory.

But the bottom line issue seems to point to these two lines of code IMO:

```
$config['BaseUrl'] = 'http://havanarumbaonline.com/web/HAVRUM/assets';

$config['BaseUrl'] = 'http://havanarumbaonline.com/web/HAVRUM/assets';
```

Any insights would be appreciated....
[image]

Comment: $config['BaseUrl'] = 'http://havanarumbaonline.com/web/HAVRUM/assets';

Comment: $config['BaseDir'] = '/home/content/28/6823828/html/havanarumba/web/HAVRUM/assets';

Comment: FTR - I also tried "/home/content/28/6823828/html/mojitotapas.com/havanarumba/web/HAVRUM/assets" --- as this is the actual hard coded path location

Comment: When I view the source code side the CKeditor, after I have placed the image, I get: "<p><img function.session-start="" src="&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;b&gt;Warning&lt;/b&gt;:  session_start() [&lt;a href=" /></p>"

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to (1) "PHP" and the version- and the (2) outdated SESSION code within the code. Once PHP was updated on the server and the SESSION_REGISTER code was updated.